# How do I multiply columns of a dataset by a constant?

Tags: r

I am quite new to R so eggscuse my lack of ability. I have tried and failed a fair bit, and would appreciate any input.

I am asked to get rid of inconsistent use of "." and "," to indicate decimals by multiplying every number in certain columns by some multiple of 10. I have tried to simply multiply using the binary operator * but it obviously doesnt work as some columns are factors, which is required in this case.

I have tried using this code aswell but get erros :subscript "Var" cant be "NA"

```
data %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ . * 1000)
```

Below is the code I have for my dataset

```
datat <- c("Starting_year" , "Rank" , "Team" , "Home_total_Games", "Home_Total_Attendance" , "Home_Avg_Attendance" , "Home_capacity" , "Away_Total_Attendance" , "Away_Avg_Attendance" , "Away_Capacity")
names(data) <- datat
```

Factors assigned

```
data$Rank <- as.factor(data$Rank)
data$Starting_year <- as.factor(data$Starting_year)
```

Thanks in advance

Cant embed but there is a picture below of the data. I am asked to use a function in dplyr to multiply the columns by 1000 to remove all the . and ,

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xEy5.png)

Comment: Please provide MRE, without knowing what exactly is the problem, we can't help you.

Comment: I have edited the post with more information now

Comment: Use `dput(head(x))` to provide a sample of data, if you can share the data. Do not provide screenshots, we can't copy and test solutions from screenshots.

Provide an exact definition of problem with a sample input (particular string) and sample output (how you would like your string to look like).

Comment: What should happen to the number 1000,5 and what should happen to 169.5 ?

Answer (score 1):

What is the format of numbers?

If the format is: `1.000.000,5`, where `.` is a thousand separator, while `,` is a decimal separator, just use gsub:

```
foo = "1.000.000,5"
bar = gsub("\\.", "", foo) # "1000000,5"
baz = gsub(",", "\\.", bar) # "1000000.5"
as.numeric(baz)
```

In this case, `factor` is not a problem because `gsub` will de-factor the vector.

If you need to multiply the numbers after that, it is not a problem. Transform this into a function (such as `convert_decimal`) and apply it to columns you want:

```
data$column = convert_decimal(data$column)
```

For multiple selected columns (let's call the vector of names `selection`):

```
data[selection] = lapply(data[selection], convert_decimal)
```

Comment: Thanks. No clue about `dplyr`, I don't use tidyverse. The suggested solution should work for the presented problem. Multiplying columns by a certain factor to remove decimal comma will obviously not work.